# rxjs forkJoin nested observable inside another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is two set of observable (network requests). 
After first observable resolved, i need to `forkJoin` multiple observable.
But in return instead of data i'm getting a `Subscriber`.

Kindly check the thid fiddle
https://stackblitz.com/edit/zj3mhp?file=index.ts

```
import { forkJoin, of, timer } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

let array = [of({ data: [1] }), of({ data: [2] })];
const init = of({ pages: 2 });

function gerData() {
  const observable = forkJoin(array);
  return init.pipe(
    map(data => {
      return observable.subscribe(data => {
        const arr = [];
        data.forEach(x => {
          arr.push(...x.data);
        });
        console.log('array', arr);
        return arr;
      });
    })
  );
}



gerData().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('final data: ', data);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mergeMap()` instead of map(), returning a subscription is not going to help.

Whatever we return in a `map()` that will be the value received in the success callback of a subscription. We can not retrieve the values from a subscription object.

In `mergeMap` we return an Observable which will be merged with the parent observable and we can get the value of the merged observable using a single subscription.

```
import { forkJoin, of, timer } from "rxjs";
import { map, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

let array = [of({ data: [1] }), of({ data: [2] })];
const init = of({ pages: 2 });

function gerData() {
  const observable = forkJoin(array);
  return init.pipe(
    mergeMap(data => {
      return observable.pipe(map(data => {
        const arr = [];
        data.forEach(x => {
          arr.push(...x.data);
        });
        console.log('array', arr);
        return arr;
      }));
    })
  );
}



gerData().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('final data: ', data);
})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/zj3mhp-elrkur?file=index.ts

Comment: @SumitRidhal Updated the answer.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
function gerData() {
  const observable = forkJoin(array);
  return init.pipe(
    switchMap(() => observable),
    map(res => res.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.data), []))
  );
}

gerData().subscribe(data => {
  console.log("final data: ", data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you subscribe to an `observable` it starts executing and is turned into an `subscription`, you should return `observable` and use `switchMap` to run that observable instead. Please try the following:

```
function gerData() {
  return init.pipe(switchMap(data=>
    forkJoin(array).pipe(map(arr=>arr.map(item=>item.data)))
  ));
}
```